# Do I need to install public keys on all target machines (Capistrano)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, unix, deployment, capistrano

I am using Capistrano to deploy our code to many machines (**several to hundreds** ).

I am going to use Capistrano to do this. From my knowledge, I need to generate a pair of public-private key for SSH login used by Capistrano; and I think I may need to install my public key to **all of my target machines**. Am I right?

Is there a better way to do this? It's tedious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, is the only way to authenticate with the remote server, otherwise you must to use an user and password.

We actually are using Puppet to install the base system and the public key. Then you can deploy with capistrano.

Answer (score 1):

No solace from me, either.

But try to see it this way: if you have `x` machines to deploy to, without public key cryptography you would have to login in with password `x * #deployments` times. Now you have to just login `x` times. The more you deploy, the bigger the advantage will be.

Of course, if you just plan to deploy just once or twice, then there might be only minimal advantage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your Capistrano script will be ssh'ing into the machine to initiate the deployment.  You should note that there will quite likely be an ssh back from the target machine to the machine that holds the files to be deployed.  As such, you'll also need to put the public keys for the target machines on the machine that handles your version control).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, to get SSH key-authenticated login, you'll need to put your public key on every machine. If deployment involves logging into a large number of separate servers then I'd suggest you're doing something wrong. The first solution that comes to mind is to have each box check out the latest working copy from a central repo following some kind of trigger (e.g. a successful CI build) but without knowing more about your project it's difficult to say what'd work best.